# How to correctly define "scope" setting in Mobile Web Application manifest.json

Tags: android-manifest, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I am trying to configure the manifest.json file correctly for my web app, so that it stays as a "standalone" feel when opened from the home screen icon.

The application is defined as a set of "pages" within the base URL: url.xyz/page1, url.xyz/page2, url.xyz/page3 etc...

Android 6 Chrome 54 properly handles this, and doesn't break the native experience when navigating between these pages.  However, iOS 10.0.2 Safari doesn't handle it properly and launches a browser each time any link is selected.

Currently I have defined scope as:

"scope": "/"

Which I assume indicates to allow the root directory and subdirectories. But I can't find consistent documentation to indicate whether the scope applies in this way, or whether any pages without extensions would appear as subdirectories, thus being "out-of-scope" and triggering a browser to open.  I can't find support or documentation on wildcards such as "scope":"/*" etc... which would allow all sub-pages and subdirectories to be included in the scope.

Can anyone clarify this and possibly explain how to do this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/449